# Characteristic and minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Given $A\in\Bbb Z^{n\times n}$, is it possible to find characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$ by chinese remainder theorem if we know characteristic and minimal polynomials respectively of $A\bmod p\in\Bbb Z_p^{n\times n}$ at sufficiently many coprime $p$s?

Comment: Sure; if $P(T)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $P(T) \mod p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A \mod p$. So now you can just apply the Chinese remainder theorem to each coefficient. To determine how many primes are necessary, you would need a bound on the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. However, there are some fairly elementary bounds due to Hadamard: If the largest integer (in absolute value) in $A$ is $M$, then the determinant is at most $n^{n/2} M^n$. Consequently, the coefficient of the $k$th term in the characteristic polynomial...

Comment: which is a sum of determinants of minors, is at most: $$\binom{n}{j} (n-j)^{(n-j)/2} M^{n-j}$$